# Android UI From timetable

Tags: android, user-interface, timetable

What was used in the app 'Timetable' to save your data in the dashboard. The boxes that are shown in the dashboard.

Any refrences? or anything else i can use?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQlite database to save data.
Create a table that save data for days and times.
Then fetch it from database.